# Отведение/освобождение памяти в конструкторе/деструкторе при наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, конструктор, c++-faq

Здравствуйте.
Начинаю разбираться в механизме наследования конструкторов/деструкторов в С++ , чувствую, что перестала что-либо понимать, решая следующую проблему.

Структура программы примерно следующая:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { mas1 = new int[10]; cout << "create A" << endl; };
    ~A() { delete[]mas1; cout << "destroy A" << endl;};
    int *mas1;
    A(const A& a) { mas1 = a.mas1; cout << "copy A" << endl;};
};
```

class B {
public:
    B(A a) { mas2 = new int[10]; cout << "create B" << endl;};
    ~B() { delete[] mas2; cout << "delete B" << endl; };
    int *mas2;
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C(A a) : B(a) { cout << "create C" << endl; };
    ~C() { cout << "delete C" << endl; };
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B *b = new C(a);
    return 0;
}

На выходе:

```
create A
copy A
copy A
create B
destroy A
create C
```

Вопрос: как поправить положение? При удалении копии А, видимо, память тоже освобождается, и при попытке удалить вторую копию все падает.
Класс В абстрактный на самом деле, отсюда создание указателя на него и иницализация потомком.

P.S. Если убрать отведение/удаление памяти в классе A, не срабатывает деструктор B и C. Но по крайней мере не падает, как и ожидалось.

Answer (score 3):

в вашем коде куча ошибок и как следствие непонимание всего происходящего

даже незнаю с какой начать...

1) необходимо сделать деструктор класса `B` (этот класс у вас не виртуальный пока нет ни одной виртуальной функции внутри) виртуальным чтобы гарантировать вызов деструкторов всех его наследников, тоесть в вашем случае деструктора `C`

```
class B 
{
public:
    B(A a) { mas2 = new int[10]; cout << "create B" << endl;};
    virtual ~B() { delete[] mas2; cout << "delete B" << endl; }; // 
    int *mas2;
};
```

2) в функции `main` освобождайте пожалуйста динамически выделенную память с помощью оператора `delete` -

`B *b = new C(a);
 delete b;`

3) классы `A` и `B` у вас управляют динамическими ресурсами `int* mas1; int* mas2;` которыми нужно корректно манипулировать при копировании, присвоении и удалении, иными словами использовать [правило трёх](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), причём применяя [глубокое копирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.AF.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), иначе возможны случаи повторного освобождения одной и той же области памяти, например, что привело бы к неопределённому поведению

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос: как поправить положение?

Соблюсти [Правило Трех](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). То есть еще написать корректные конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания.

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваши объекты *единолично* владели своими ресурсами (в данном случае - динамическими массивами), то они его должны корректно копировать. При копировании объекта новый объект должен получать свою, отдельную копию ресурса. Ваш конструктор копирования

```
A(const A& a) { mas1 = a.mas1; cout << "copy A" << endl;};
```

не подойдет, ибо это не глубокое копирование. Ваши объекты не умеют совместно владеть одним и тем же массивом.

Это относится и к классу `A`, и к классу `B`.

---

Если же вы хотите, чтобы ваши объекты умели *совместно* владеть одним и тем же ресурсом - то это совсем другая история. `std::shared_ptr` поможет вам решить эту задачу.

Но что именно вам нужно - отсюда не видно.